# Disabling "block selection" on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, selection, copy-paste

I am building an app for iPhone that has JavaScript running in a webview.  When the new auto-select block selection tool is used to select text, and the block is resized from the side, it makes my JavaScript freak out. Does anyone know a way to disable the copy/paste for block selection? I still need to be able to select the text, just not using the big selection tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is nothing in the UIWebView API to allow this. Your best bet is probably to tweak it from the JS side of things.

Comment: this is the closest thing i could find to a real answer lol.  I think I figured it out though, the block selection sometimes adds either a line return or just lots of whitespace at the end of the selection, which can cause things to hiccup, so if anyone else comes across this problem, that is probably it